# Data Factory copy csv to SQL cannot convert empty data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Encountered below various errors caused by empty data when building a very basic Copy Data task from File Sharing to Azure SQL:

> ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting
> value '' for column name 'EndDate' from type 'String' (precision:,
> scale:) to type 'DateTime' (precision:255, scale:255). Additional
> info: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

And here is another one I believe caused by the same reason:

> ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting
> value '' for column name 'ContractID' from type 'String' (precision:,
> scale:) to type 'Guid' (precision:255, scale:255). Additional info:
> Unrecognized Guid format.

All I need is to treat empty data as NULL when copying to SQL Tables. The only option I have found is "Null value" in my CSV dataset; and it is set to nothing as default.

Below is the code of CSV dataset:

```
{
    "name": "CSV",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "CSV",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "FileName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureFileStorageLocation",
                "fileName": {
                    "value": "@dataset().FileName",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "folderPath": "output"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}
```

The csv file does use double quotation marks as the qualifier. And those empty data in source files look like this:

```
"b139fe4d-f48a-4158-8196-a43500b3bf02","19601","Bar","2015/02/02","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the Copy Activity cann't process the empty value, so we need to use Data Flow to Convert the field to NULL value.

Here is my test using your example:

1. I created a table in Azure SQL

```sql
Create table TestNull(
    Column1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER null,
    Column2 varchar(50) null,
    Column3 varchar(60) null,
    Column4 DateTime null,
    Column5 varchar(50) null,
    Column6 varchar(50) null
)
```

2. In ADF, We can use DerivedColumn to convert the empty value to NULL value. So we can use the expression `iifNull(Column_1,toString(null()))` to judge the if the field is empty, if so it will be replaced with a NULL value.

[image]

3. In the sink, we should set the mapping.

[image]

4. It will insert NULL value into the table.

[image]

Comment: Just unbelievable...why such a common parsing was left out by M$ while replacing SSIS with ADF. Now my problem is that I use parameter to copy whole bunch of files to corresponding tables, therefore I am reluctant to use data flow unless it can detect all empty fields from all possible columns and replace with NULL somehow. Do you know a way to do it?

Comment: Because there is no way to manipulate the data during the copy activity in ADF.

Comment: Thank you so much anyway. So as I'm using parameters to loop through a list of files and load all of them, is there an easy way to smartly pick up all empty data and derive them while mapping in data flow?

Comment: Do the files in the file list have dynamic column count?

Comment: Yes they all.have different number of columns

Comment: It will be a little complicated, could you please ask another question about how to convert null value with dynamic columns and show us some details ? Thanks.

Comment: "Because there is no way to manipulate the data during the copy activity in ADF." doesn't really seem like a good explanation. When using unquoted CSV files it converts empty entries to `NULL` fine

Comment: @Martin Smith Could you please show us how to do that? Thanks!