# String To DateTime Error in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, csv, datetime, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to import data from a CSV to Azure SQL and there seems to be an issue with ADF importing a datetime column. I'm using ADF V2 and all the online help seems to show fixes for ADF V1.

The date column is in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format in the source CSV and the destination Azure SQL  is datetime format, so should work perfectly, but it doesn't.
ADF seems to collect all data in the CSV as a string and then throw out an error saying cant convert string to datetime.

ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '04-Apr-22 00:00:00' for column name 'DateTime' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'DateTime' (precision:23, scale:3). Additional info: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I have tried using the type version setting in the Mapping, but that doesn't work. I've tried every datetime format I can think of.

[image]

Any help solving this would be much appreciated

Comment: I get this too now, I don't think it was a problem a year ago, just noticed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without setting a DateTime format in the mapping settings?

[image]

Comment: Yes I only added the DateTime format because it didn't work without it, and a post I saw suggested it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the error the data being converted was this: '04-Apr-22 00:00:00'
So your date time format should be dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening where you have empty value in concerned column in CSV.

You can use fault tolerance in settings of copy activity and give a logs path to know what exact rows are responsible for the error.

There is a solution proposed for this kind of problem in this link [Data Factory copy csv to SQL cannot convert empty data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419669/data-factory-copy-csv-to-sql-cannot-convert-empty-data)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Che.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).